# Quorum - Ethereum interaction

Tags: quorum

how to connect the quorum blockchain with the ethereum network using the bridge services.Can anyone clarify me about the bridge concept and how to implement it in quorum ethereum connection?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of bridge services readily available for Ethereum and Quorum, obviously the use will depend on your exact use case, but here are a selection of projects for you to review:

- Parity Bridge: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridge
- Ion: https://github.com/clearmatics/ion
- And here is a sample project of having 2 Quorum blockchains implementing a custom exchange bridge: https://github.com/M-Bowe/pons & https://github.com/M-Bowe/pons-frontend